# How to summarize values in DataFrame between defined values in column in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sum, aggregation, numeric

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

Data types:

- MONTH_NR - numeric
- MONTH_NAME - object
- VALUE - numeric

  | MONTH_NR | MONTH_NAME | VALUE |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 1 | JANUARY | 10 |
  | 2 | FEBRYARY | 20 |
  | 3 | MARCH | 15 |
  | 4 | APRIL | 10 |
  | 5 | MAY | 11 |
  | 6 | JUN | 100 |
  | 7 | JULY | 200 |
  | 8 | AUGUST | 12 |
  | 9 | SEPTEMBER | 20 |
  | 10 | OCTOBER | 50 |
  | 11 | NOVEMBER | 30 |
  | 12 | DECEMBER | 50 |

And I need to add 3 new ROWS where will be:

1. sum of values from column "VALUE" after 6 month (from 1 till 6)
2. sum of values from column "VALUE" after 12 month (from 7 till 12)
3. sum of values from column "VALUE" after 12 month (from 1 till 12)

So as a result I need somethin like below:

```
    MONTH_NR | MONTH_NAME  | VALUE
    ---------|-------------|---------
    1        | JANUARY     |  10
    2        | FEBRYARY    |  20
    3        | MARCH       |  15
    4        | APRIL       |  10
    5        | MAY         |  11
    6        | JUN         |  100
SUM_AFTER_1_6|             |  166
    7        | JULY        |  200
    8        | AUGUST      |  12
    9        | SEPTEMBER   |  20
    10       | OCTOBER     |  50
    11       | NOVEMBER    |  30
    12       | DECEMBER    |  50
SUM_AFTER_7_12|             |  362
SUM_ALL      |             |  528
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: answered. But why do you need such a heterogeneous dataframe, visually view the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a nested list `aaa` is created in which the name and two indexes for the range in which the sums will be turn out through `loc`(note that slices in loc are taken inclusive. For example `df.loc[0:5, 'VALUE']` would take rows 0 through 5, that is six rows.).

Further, in the `List comprehension`, a nested list is also created where the name, an empty string and the sum in each value inside the list. With `np.insert`, rows are inserted and the dataframe is overwritten and the original column names are set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('df1.csv', header=0)

aaa = [['SUM_AFTER_1_6', 0, 5], ['SUM_AFTER_7_12', 6, 11], ['SUM_ALL', 0, 11]]
bbb = [[aaa[i][0], '', df.loc[aaa[i][1]:aaa[i][2], 'VALUE'].sum()] for i in range(len(aaa))]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.insert(df.values, [6, 12, 12], values=bbb, axis=0))

df.rename(columns={0: 'MONTH_NR', 1: 'MONTH_NAME', 2: 'VALUE'}, inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Output

```
          MONTH_NR MONTH_NAME VALUE
0                1    JANUARY    10
1                2   FEBRYARY    20
2                3      MARCH    15
3                4      APRIL    10
4                5        MAY    11
5                6        JUN   100
6    SUM_AFTER_1_6              166
7                7       JULY   200
8                8     AUGUST    12
9                9  SEPTEMBER    20
10              10    OCTOBER    50
11              11   NOVEMBER    30
12              12   DECEMBER    50
13  SUM_AFTER_7_12              362
14         SUM_ALL              528
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested approach:

- add column order_num to df, my calculating month_nr * 10
- calculate summary rows (into another df), with order_num = 65 for 1-6 sum, 125 for 7-12 sum and 130 for 1-12 sum
- add calculated rows to original df
- output df ordered by order_num

Comment: bracko could you present example code please ? :)